# PRIME NUMBER is the relation given always true or is it false, $2^n-1$

Tags: prime-numbers

If n is a prime no. Is it necessary that $2^n - 1$ is also a prime no.
I know that the converse is true, but i want to know about this statement.
If it's wrong plz. Give an eg. If its right plz. Prove it.

Comment: False probably for most primes $n$. Smallest counterexample is $n=11$.

Comment: Plz guys I am not that good in Maths plz. Be soft. Thnx for your answers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime

Answer (score 1):

Check if  $2^{11}-1$ is prime. It's merely the fifth candidate ...